# System commands in c#

Tags: c#, linux, command, system

Does C# have an equivalent to the system command in C? for example,

how would I do this in c#?.

```
    system("ls -al");
```

I'm using Mono on Linux.

Comment: So many down votes yet a similar question in python gets over 1000 up votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem I got it.

```
public static void system(string command)
    {
        //No arguments
        if(command.IndexOf(' ')== -1)
        {
            Process.Start(command);
        }
        else 
        {
            string cmd = command.Substring(0, command.IndexOf(' '));
            string args = command.Substring(command.IndexOf(' ')+1);
            Process.Start(cmd, args);
        }
    }
```

Tested and working on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: wouldn't work for `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`

Comment: Good point, should have mentioned this is for Linux. Tested on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.Start() method.
Look at [ProcessStartinfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)